# How i can convert chr column into date in R?

Tags: r, date, datetime

I have a data frame in R (xlsx file imported) that the first column contain dates with character type:

```
> dat
# A tibble: 4,372 x 3
   date    `1`   `2`
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 40544  35.5  35.5
 2 40545  35.6  35.8
 3 40546  37.2  36.4
 4 40547  36.7  35.4
 5 40548  36.6  35.3
```

I want to convert the character type into date type in R.
I tried the below code but NA's occur:

```
> dat%>%
+   mutate(date2 = as.Date(date, format= "%m-%d-%Y"))
# A tibble: 4,372 x 4
   date    `1`   `2` date2 
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <date>
 1 40544  35.5  35.5 NA    
 2 40545  35.6  35.8 NA    
 3 40546  37.2  36.4 NA    
 4 40547  36.7  35.4 NA    
 5 40548  36.6  35.3 NA
```

How can i fix this ?
Any help ?

Comment: Try `as.Date(as.numeric(date), origin = ...)`.

Comment: what i put in the origin argument ?

Comment: my starting date  is "01-01-2011"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
dat %>%
  mutate(date2 = as.numeric(date),
         date2 = as.Date(date2, origin = "1900-01-01"))
   date      date2
1 40544 2011-01-03
2 40545 2011-01-04
3 40546 2011-01-05
4 40547 2011-01-06
```

Comment: `Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `date2 = as.Date(date, origin =
  "1900-01-01")`.
Caused by error in `charToDate()`:
! character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`

Comment: Please see edited answer. You need to convert to numeric first.